# How can I tell Chrome I want to keep the file I'm downloading?

Tags: google-chrome

After I hit download this is all I see:

[image: chrome download options]

There is no option for me to "keep" the file I'm trying to download unless I open up the download page (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) and select it there:

[image: Chrome download page]

I don't want to open the downloads page every time I download something. Is there a setting I can enable so I can choose to "Keep" the download quicker?

EDIT: `Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings - Advanced - Downloads and select "Ask where to save each file before downloading". Then I would restart Chrome.  Since it now doesn't have a default folder to download you should have more control over the file and you should be able to choose to keep.

Comment: Possible to do this without changing that setting? I don't want to tell chrome every time I download.